# Giving the user the option to select '.txt' from filesystem

Tags: c#, file

I am making a cipher decryption/encryptor Console Application.

What I would like to do is give the option for the user to be able to select a .txt file from the filesystem or type into the console window. I know how to read/write/save '.txt' etc. but I'm a little uncertain of the best way to implement it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Application
{


class Caesar
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       try{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Key:");
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("[E]   Encrypt");
        Console.WriteLine("[D]   Decrypt");
        string choice =Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToUpper();

            // WOULD LIKE TO GIVE THE USER THE CHOICE BETWEEN TYPING OR  ADDING A .TXT FILE FROM THE FILSYSTEM
        switch (choice)
        {
            case "E": Console.Write("Enter Plain Text:");
                      string pt = Console.ReadLine();
                      caesar_cipher(k, pt);
                       break;

            case "D": Console.Write("Type CipherText :");
                       string ct = Console.ReadLine();
                      caesar_decipher(k, ct);
                      break;

            default: Console.WriteLine("You've entered an incorrect option!");
                       break;
        }
       }
       catch(Exception)
       {
           Console.WriteLine ("The value you entered is incorrect");
           Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to try again");
              Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
    static void caesar_cipher(int key, string pt)
    {
        int size = pt.Length;
        char[] value = new char[size];
        char[] cipher = new char[size];
        for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
        {
            value[r] = Convert.ToChar(pt.Substring(r, 1));
        }

        for (int re = 0; re < size; re++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(value[re]);
            for (int y = 1; y <= key; y++)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    if (a == 90)
                    { a = 64; }
                    else if (a == 122)
                    { a = 96; }
                    cipher[re] = Convert.ToChar(a + y);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int b = Convert.ToInt32(cipher[re]);
                    if (b == 90)
                    { b = 64; }
                    else if (b == 122)
                    { b = 96; }
                    cipher[re] = Convert.ToChar(b + 1);

                }
            }
        }
        string ciphertext = "";

        for (int p = 0; p < size; p++)
        {
            ciphertext = ciphertext + cipher[p].ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Cipher Text=");
        Console.WriteLine(ciphertext.ToUpper());
    }


    static void caesar_decipher(int key, string ct)
    {
        int size = ct.Length;
        char[] value = new char[size];
        char[] cipher = new char[size];
        for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
        {
            cipher[r] = Convert.ToChar(ct.Substring(r, 1));
        }

        for (int re = 0; re < size; re++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(cipher[re]);
            for (int y = 1; y <= key; y++)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    if (a == 65)
                    { a = 91; }
                    else if (a == 97)
                    { a = 123; }
                    value[re] = Convert.ToChar(a - y);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int b = Convert.ToInt32(value[re]);
                    if (b == 65)
                    { b = 91; }
                    else if (b == 97)
                    { b = 123; }
                    value[re] = Convert.ToChar(b - 1);

                }
            }
        }
        string plaintext = "";

        for (int p = 0; p < size; p++)
        {
            plaintext = plaintext + value[p].ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Plain Text=");
        Console.WriteLine(plaintext.ToLower());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them to be able to choice between selecting a file from the filesystem or typing the encrypted/plain text string themselfs?

or do you want them to be able to select a file from the filesystem or type the filepath themselfs?

Assuming you mean the latter here is my solution for your problem.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            Console.Write("Enter key : ");
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Would you like to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt? : ");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            // Making the decision of writing the filepath or selecting the filepath.
            Console.Write("Would you like to [W]rite or [S]elect the file path? : ");
            string fileChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            string filePath = "";
            if(fileChoice == "W") {
                Console.WriteLine("Type the filepath the .txt file with your Cipher/Plain text");
                filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else {
                OpenFileDialog dial = new OpenFileDialog();
                dial.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
                if (dial.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    filePath = dial.FileName;
            }

            string stringData;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                stringData = reader.ReadToEnd();


            switch (choice) {
                case "E":
                    caesar_cipher(key, stringData);
                    break;

                case "D":
                    caesar_decipher(key, stringData);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You've entered an incorrect option!");
                    break;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();  // Added this to make sure you can read the end result.
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is incorrect");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Main(null); // This will call the main method allowing you to "try again".
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible method of doing this is by allowing the user to start the program by dragging and dropping a file onto the .exe - the program can then either encrypt or decrypt the contents of file. If the program is started simply by double clicking the .exe then it can assume it will encrypt or decrypt user input from the console.

You could do something like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // If args is not empty, then the user has dragged and dropped a file.
        bool inputFromFile = args.Length > 1;
        string input = string.Empty;
        if (inputFromFile)
        {
            // This contains the file path of the dragged and dropped file.
            string fileName = args[0];
            input = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        }
        else
            input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

To test this, if you are using Visual Studio, you can set the project's command line arguments using:

[image: Modification of command line arguments in Visual Studio project properties]